# Calculating the prime factors of a very big integer

Tags: python, math, prime-factoring

I am having an interesting problem with Python. My task is to calculate all prime factors of a given number. This is my code:

```
import math

def func(number):
    while number % 2 == 0:
        number = number / 2
        print("2")

    for i in range(3, math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)) + 1, 2):
        while number % i == 0:
            number = number / i
            print(i)

    if number > 2:
        print(str(int(number)))
```

Normally this code works and there is no problem. However, say we pass `211,111,122,222,223,420` to `func`. It will print these factors: `2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 19, 97, 178980536338`. This obviously can't be true as the number whose factors we want to find ends with zero, which means that it must have at least one 5 among its factors. Right? In fact, if you multiple the printed factors, the result will be `211,111,122,222,223,424` (four units more than the passed number). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is Python 3, you need to use `number // i` rather than `number / i`.  The latter will give a floating point result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `//` instead of `/`. In Python 3, the `/` operator gives you a float, which introduces inaccuracies. If you use `//` instead, you will stick with ints, which gives you the right answer.

```py
def func(number):
    while number % 2 == 0:
        number = number // 2
        print(2)
    for i in range(3, math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)) + 1, 2):
        while number % i == 0:
            number = number // i
            print(i)
    if number > 2:
        print(number)

func(211111122222223420)
```

gives

```
2
2
5
1181
1321
1747
3872893
```

Comment: You are right, @khelwood. Thank you. Problem solved. But why?! I mean, why introducing floats causes problem?

Comment: Because floats are approximations. They might be slightly off from the value you meant them to be. And then the arithmetic doesn't quite work.